# Permission denied error while setting up GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm following this page https://learntocodewith.me/tutorials/github-pages/ to create GitHub pages on MacBook Air (El Capitan) but when I do the last step I get this error:

```
$ git remote add origin 
https://github.com/azg357/azg357.github.io.git
$ GitHubPageTest a$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to azg357/azg357.github.io.git denied to zeynel1.
fatal: unable to access 
'https://github.com/azg357/azg357.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
$
```

It looks like permission to access the repository is denied to "zeynel1". I use names like "zeynel" or "zeynel1" because it is my first name, but in this case, I haven't used it! I don't know where this is coming from.

Just before this error, OSX asks permission to give permission to GitHub to access "osxkeychain". Is this related to this? The message says something like "git-credential-osxkeychain" cannot be verified.

This is the copy of the entire session:

```
as-MacBook-Air:azeynel a$ cd /Users/a/GitHubPageTest 
as-MacBook-Air:GitHubPageTest a$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/a/GitHubPageTest/.git/
as-MacBook-Air:GitHubPageTest a$ git add .
as-MacBook-Air:GitHubPageTest a$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) ad86580] first commit
1 file changed, 7 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 index.html
as-MacBook-Air:GitHubPageTest a$ git remote add origin 
https://github.com/azg357/azg357.github.io.git
as-MacBook-Air:GitHubPageTest a$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to azg357/azg357.github.io.git denied to zeynel1.
fatal: unable to access 
'https://github.com/azg357/azg357.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
as-MacBook-Air:GitHubPageTest a$
```

Thanks!

.

Comment: Read this: https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git

Comment: I read it and tried again but I got the same error.

Comment: I already had a primary email at GitHub set up.

Comment: And did you configure git (using the instructions linked in my first comment) to set your local git email to that same address? Who is the owner of the repo azg357.github.io.git?

Comment: I'm the owner. I already have an email and a primary email showing on GitHub. So I cannot add the same email again as instructed in the page you linked.

Comment: And my email starts with "zeynel11111" not "zeynel1" as in the error?

Comment: Read my comment, carefully. Read the page I linked to, carefully. I'm not telling you to add the same primary email on github a second time. I'm telling you to configure your local git to use the same email address as the one you configured on github. So that, when you use git to talk to github, it can identify you thanks to that email address.

Comment: Are you referring to this page https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github ? I followed the instructions there and I did `git config --global user.email "email@example.com"` and confirmed that it was set. Do I need to do anything more?

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem caused by the cache on Key chain app. I deleted the stored GitHub items and it worked.